# android timezone difference is 1 hour less then expected

Tags: android, timezone

What I need is a time difference between specific timezone ("Russia/Moscow") and local time of the user, difference should be in hours.

I run into problem that the Difference of Time Zones is sometimes false calculated. I calculate difference (in hours) between local offset to UTC of android device and remote offset to UTC. For most user it is fine.. but many user are complaining about the problem.. I am not able to reproduce it at my phone or emulators.
The "wrong" displayed time difference is all ways 1 hour less.
In Moscow it is 15:00, in Europe 12:00. But the user see the offset of 2 hours
here is my code.

```
 String tz="Europe/Moscow"
 Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
 mCalendar.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz));
 TimeZone mTimeZone = mCalendar.getTimeZone();  
 int remote = mTimeZone.getRawOffset()/1000/60/60;

 Calendar mCalendar2 = new GregorianCalendar();
 TimeZone mTimeZone2 = mCalendar2.getTimeZone();  
 int local = mTimeZone2.getRawOffset()/1000/60/60;

 return local - remote;
```

Comment: Does your clock go forward/backwards twice a year due to "Summer Time"/"Daylight Savings Time"? Look at the numbers you get before you do the subtraction.

Comment: I do not know.. because it doesn't happens to me. By my phone is everything ok. these are bug reports from user.. :(

Comment: Moscow is 4 hours ahead of London currently, although in summer it'll be 3 hours ahead as UK puts the clock forward an hour in Spring. Other countries will do the same. Are you taking this into account? Is there a pattern between the users complaining and the ones who aren't? Look at the time in those countries, and whether they change their clocks.

Answer (score 4):

You are making the common mistake of equating a *Time Zone* with a *Time Zone Offset*.  They are two different things.  Please read the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

When you call `getRawOffset`, that returns the *standard* offset for that time zone.  To get the offset that's in effect at a particular point in time, you can use `getOffset`, which takes a parameter of the timestamp for the point in time you are talking about.

Consider the following code, which returns the difference that is *currently* in effect:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

String tz = "Europe/Moscow";
TimeZone mTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz);  
int remote = mTimeZone.getOffset(now);

TimeZone mTimeZone2 = TimeZone.getDefault();  
int local = mTimeZone2.getOffset(now);

double differenceInHours = (local - remote) / 3600000.0;

return differenceInHours;
```

Note a couple of things:

- I did not need a `Calendar` class.
- The offsets are both for the same "now".  You will get different results depending on when you run it.
- Not all offsets use a whole number of hours, so this function should return `double`, not `int`.  For example, try `Asia/Kolkata`, which uses UTC+5:30 the whole year, or `Australia/Adelaide`, which alternates between UTC+9:30 and UTC+10:30.

Consider also using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), which is a much more robust way of working with time in Java.