# android: timezone offset for "Europe/Russia"

Tags: android, time, timezone

I need an offset for "Europe/Russia" to UTC.. in hours. here is my code:

```
Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
mCalendar.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
TimeZone mTimeZone = mCalendar.getTimeZone();  
int remote_offset = mTimeZone.getRawOffset()/1000/60/60;
```

For UTC it should be -4 hours. BUT! some user got 3 hours difference!!

I think, the problem is, Russia doesn't use winter time. And some devices now that, but some not.. how could I implement allway to get "-4" hours?

Regards

Comment: Europe/Russia is not a valid time zone identifier, at least not in IANA-tzdb. Their naming scheme is {continent}/{exemplar-city}.

Comment: @MenoHochschild you're right and counting that not all timezones in russia are Moscow.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Indeed, Russia is much much bigger than Moscow. And the problem is what Java is doing with an invalid identifier, namely just mapping to GMT+00:00!

Comment: @user1908375 - Please don't post the same thing twice.  If you have more to add to [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646807), you can always edit it.

Comment: I am sorry.. it's a here.. I use "EUrope/Moscow"

Answer (score 3):

First, Russia isn't UTC-4.

The problem has to do with Russia not having daylight saving time. But your issue is probably only happening with android 2.x device and less. The daylight saving time was removed before 4.x as far as I remember (if it's a user input). On the other hand, if you receive a date that was created by the device without user input, you don't have to convert it as it's already as UTC.

But as I said, Russia isn't -4. Russia/Moscow will be +4 hours. But Russia is larger than Moscow really!

Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia

```
UTC+03:00   MSK−1: Kaliningrad Time    Europe/Kaliningrad
UTC+04:00   MSK:   Moscow Time         Europe/Moscow, Europe/Volgograd, Europe/Samara
UTC+06:00   MSK+2: Yekaterinburg Time  Asia/Yekaterinburg
UTC+07:00   MSK+3: Omsk Time           Asia/Omsk, Asia/Novosibirsk, Asia/Novokuznetsk
UTC+08:00   MSK+4: Krasnoyarsk Time    Asia/Krasnoyarsk
UTC+09:00   MSK+5: Irkutsk Time        Asia/Irkutsk
UTC+10:00   MSK+6: Yakutsk Time        Asia/Yakutsk
UTC+11:00   MSK+7: Vladivostok Time    Asia/Vladivostok, Asia/Sakhalin
UTC+12:00   MSK+8: Magadan Time        Asia/Magadan, Asia/Kamchatka, Asia/Anadyr
```

So what you'll have to do is to check if we're in winter and that the TimeZone is one of those. If the timezone is one of those, you can add one more hour when you want to show. And remove 1 hour when you want to convert to UTC.

I don't believe it's possible to update the TimeZone on the android phones and that also means that it's not exactly possible to do that unless you find an alternative library for Dates that has timezones built-in and which are updated.

You could subclass the DateObject with the functions that you use to behave just like the old date object, all you'll have to do is to make sure it behaves differently on android2.x and not on android 4.x+.

Also check this: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

I checked there and I guess it could be usable and less hacky than my suggestion above. The TimeZones are up to date so it could just work for every phone since it shouldn't use the internal timezones. On the other hand, if you have functions that require the Date, it might get tricky.

My suggestion is make sure you use UTC everywhere and use JodaTime to format the date with timezones and to do "datetime" operations. If you make sure that your Java Date never contain a TimeZone other than UTC. It should work.

Comment: I am sorry for my typo.. I use "Europe/Moscow".